# How do I change ListView data that is stored in a Fragment (being loaded in mainactivity) through another activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, callback, onactivityresult

Okay, so my question might be a bit hard to understand so I'll try to explain it more clearly.

I have 3 files, 1 file is a fragment which has a ListView and that file extends ListFragment, another file which is the main activity where the fragment is being loaded into and an activity where i can add data to my list.

However, I can't get this to work. I keep getting a NullPointerException and you can call me stupid but I really don't know why I am getting one.

Fragment.java

```
public ProductListAdapter adapter;
List<Task> tasks = new Data().returnData();
public MyFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_todo,tasks);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

There is more to handle the clicking but what I posted now is what handles the adapter setting.

MainActivity.java

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_add) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AddItems.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE_2);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(data.getExtras().containsKey("name")){
        Bundle b = data.getExtras();
        Task t = new Task(b);
        Data data1 = new Data();
        data1.addTask(t);

        //the next two lines causes the NPE. This was just something I tried but it didn't want to work
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        myFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

AddItem.java

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Task task = new Task(etName.getText().toString(),etDate.getText().toString(),etDetail.getText().toString());
            Intent i = getIntent();
            Bundle b = task.toBundle();
            i.putExtra("name",b);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();

          //Note that adding Myfragment myfragment{...} in this file will throw an NPE here as well.
        }
});
```

What I was thinking is that I am not actually passing the data back to MyFragment or that I somehow can't read the adapter in a different class (the adapter is set to public).

I've tried to implement the fragment using java code like so:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.myContainer,new MyFragment()).commit();
```

and then trying to call the notify data set changed, it didnt give me any errors but it still did not update the ListView so I deleted it.

Can somehow help me? I am stuck with this for a while now.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

edit 1: Ok so i changed the code in onActivityResult to this, it stopped giving me a NullPointerException but the data is not being updated yet.

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(data.getExtras().containsKey("name")){
        Task t = new Task(data.getExtras());
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        myFragment.tasks.add(3,t);
        ProductListAdapter adapter = new ProductListAdapter(this,R.layout.list_todo,myFragment.tasks);
        myFragment.adapter = adapter;
        myFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Edit 2: I have chaned the codes in MainActivity and in MyFragment
MainActivity:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(data.getExtras().containsKey("name")){
        Task t = new Task(data.getExtras());
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        myFragment.setArguments(t.toBundle());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.myContainer,myFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

MyFragment:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_todo,tasks);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment,container,false);

    if(getActivity().getIntent().getExtras() != null){
        Bundle b = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        Task task = new Task(b);
        tasks.add(task);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

I am not getting a nullpointer anymore but ListView is;t updating, even tho I have set an notiffyDataSetChanged(). I've probably put it in the wrong spot but I don't know where else to put it.

Comment: bit confused with how you are doing it. 
You make a new instance of 'myfragment' but you do not add it to the fragment manager anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: in onActivityResult(), you make a new object of MyFragment. But that is never added to fragment transaction i.e. no calls like beginTransaction, commit etc. Any particular reasons to treat your Fragment class as a normal java class but not as android framework's fragment?

Comment: you mean: `if(data.getExtras().containsKey("name")){
            Task t = new Task(data.getExtras());
            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            myFragment.setArguments(t.toBundle());
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.myContainer,myFragment).commit();
        }`? That still doesn't work tho, the ListView is not being updated